# The signal "from" or "of" diffusing probes

Tags: grammar

What is more common or correct?

> The signal from diffusing probes can be estimated by ...

or

> The signal of diffusing probes can be  estimated by...

As I understand it, "from" indicates origin and "of" possession, but somehow both meanings seem to fit quite well here.

Comment: They both work in this context, but be uniform throughout your work.

Comment: If you mean electric signals, then *from* is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originating would probably be the better choice as it relates to the work but either would work and be perfectly understandable.